# IFrame: Running an Iframe on Chrome but want to keep IE settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Right now I have a webpage that renders differently on internet explorer than chrome. I want to load an iframe that holds this webpage. When the webpage is shown within the iframe I want it to render in the way it renders on Internet Explorer. Is there a way to ensure that even users who run this application on chrome/firefox will see the iframe loaded with the internet explorer configuration? I was not sure if the iframe automatically conforms to the browser the webpage is being run on or if there is a way to change the iframe to have it render the way a specific browser would?

Comment: An iFrame in Chrome is still chrome. If it looks 'right' in IE but not chrome, that means your web site is broken.

Comment: No. Many of your users (e.g., those on Mac, Linux, iOS, Android) won't even have IE installed.

Answer (score 3):

No, the page within the iframe will be rendered by whatever browser is rendering the parent page.

Instead, you should focus your efforts on developing a website that operates correctly in all of your target browsers rather than just IE.

Answer (score -1):

There is a vague chance you can do it with CSS but it's highly unlikely. What renders web pages in a certain way is the browser of the user themselves. That's what translates the HTML and that's why your code looks different, because Chrome translates it one way, and Internet Explorer a different way (by the way no one uses IE since XP).

Comment: "*by the way no one uses IE since XP*" that is so far from the truth.